# Не могу понять в каком направлении двигаться дальше(PHP)

Tags: php, cms

Недавно написал простенький движок для сайта: https://github.com/Trojan4ik/MyLinked-CMS , но не могу понять что на данный момент в моем коде не так, что стоит добавить и что я делал неправильно.

Comment: Вопрос должен быть конкретным и не состоять из ссылки на проект.

Comment: Допустим, отказаться от MD5 для шифрования паролей. Даже двойной `md5` можно взломать(Гуглите радужную таблицу). PHP имеет более современные способы шифрования.

Comment: @NTP *хэширования.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Разберите один из многих современных Фрейморков (Symfony, Laravel,
   Yii)
2. Почитайте о архитектуре MVC
3. Стандарты PSR
4. SOLID в обязательном порядке

Если это разберете, дальше я думаю и сами поймете куда двигаться.
То что Вы написали это не движок, это говнокод с кучей уязвимостей.